# Formatting a JS array into specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, handlebars.js, lodash

I have a Javascript array

```
var arr = ['[dim].[att].&[123]','[dim].[att5].&[123]','[dim4].[att].&[123]','[dim3].[att].&[123]','[dim].[att].&[222]']
```

from this array I need to produce output like this:

`var str  = " 'dim'[att] = 123 ||  'dim'[att] = 222 ,  'dim'[att5] = 123 , 'dim4'[att] = 123 , 'dim3'[att] = 123  ";`.

I  first need to split each value in the array by `.&` and then I need to group all the items by `index 0` of the resultant array. So in this case I will group `[dim].[att].&[123]` & `[dim].[att].&[222]` becuase of `[dim].[att]`

From each of these items, now I need to split by `].` and produce requires output such that `[dim].[att].&[123]` **becomes** `'dim'[att] = 123`

**I do not want to use multiple for loops for this purpose**. I already have that solution ready. So far i am able to group the items, but not sure how to generate required output. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1fzt0nq/) for my solution

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `Array.map` and `Array.join`

```
var str = arr.map(function(s){
    var a = s.match(/\w+/g);
    return "'" + a[0] + "'[" + a[1] + "] = " + a[2];
}).join("||");
```

In the above, we are taking the three parts which we want into an Array using `s.match(/\w+/g)` and then returning in the format we want.

Also, at last, `Array.join` is called with `||` as the `String`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/526nbb4h/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking at your solution, I am not sure, how you are spliting the value & what is the use of `s.match(/\w+/g);`. If I just run your solution, I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: @SharpCoder it was a little typo. Now it should work

Comment: Thank you for help. Your answer is partially correct. I am voting up for your help. `||` should only be applied when memebers are from same [dim].[Att].

Comment: Can you please tell me what is `s.match(/\w+/g)` line doing?

Comment: @SharpCoder it is making an array of `dim`, `att`, `123`..and so on. `\w+` means match any alpha-numerical characters.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this; Code below and [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/933m79h7/)

```
var arr = ['[dim].[att].&[123]', '[dim].[att5].&[123]', '[dim4].[att].&[123]', '[dim3].[att].&[123]', '[dim].[att].&[222]']

var res = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy(function (x) {
    return x.match(/.+?\.&/i)[0];
})
.map(function(y) {
    return _.map(y, function (z) {
        var a = z.match(/\w+/g);
        return "'" + a[0] + "'[" + a[1] + "] = " + a[2];
    }).join(" || ");
})
    .value().join(", ");

console.log(res)
```